# Query Search. Order users by number of publications

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a problem with a query, I hope you can help me.
I have two tables.

### Users

id_user |
name  |
date

### Publications

id_publication |
publication |
date |
id_user

I want the first results (users) are the ones who have published

I have this query.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (name LIKE  '%" . $word . "%') ORDER BY (SELECT id_user, count(*) FROM publications GROUP BY id_user) DESC
```

But I not have  the desired result

i want a query in form of search where print all users and order by the number of publications. For example.. if in table user this the name : Maria, Angela. And Maria have more publications, the first to appear is the name of Maria.

thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

You can join both of the tables as follows to get the desired result:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id_user, COUNT(Publication) AS PubCount
 FROM Publications
 GROUP BY id_user
) as T
ON T.id_user = Users.is_User
ORDER BY T.PubCount DESC
```

Comment: thanks Guranjuan Singh for answering! 
I worked the query Majid

Comment: @user3462094 if you find answers to be helpful, please accept them and/or vote them up.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users us WHERE (name LIKE '%" . $word . "%') 
ORDER BY (SELECT count(*) FROM publications pub WHERE us.id_user = pub.id_user) DESC
```